# Encrypt a NSString using RSA algorithm

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption

I have **a exponent and a modulus**. **How do i encrypt a NSString using RSA algorithm**. I have gone through many forums. But still find it confusing. Can anyone give me the right way to encrypt a **NSString** using **RSA algorithm** with the exponent and modulus?

I currently try this. But still get a wrong encrypted string

```
publicTag = [self PublicKeyItems];
SecKeyRef publicKeyData = [self getPublicKeyRef];

NSString* result = (NSString*)[self encryptRSA:@"Shob" key:publicKeyData];
```

And the following implementations

```
- (NSData *)PublicKeyItems
{
    NSMutableArray *publicarray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [publicarray addObject:encryptionExponent];
    [publicarray addObject:encryptionModulus];
    NSData *testData = [publicarray berData];
    NSLog(@"testdata = %@",testData);
    return testData;
}

-(SecKeyRef)getPublicKeyRef 
{

OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
SecKeyRef publicKeyReference = NULL;

if (publicKeyReference == NULL) {
    [self generateKeyPair:512];
    NSMutableDictionary *queryPublicKey = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    // Set the public key query dictionary.
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassKey forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
    [queryPublicKey setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];


    // Get the key.
    sanityCheck = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryPublicKey, (CFTypeRef *)&publicKeyReference);


    if (sanityCheck != noErr)
    {
        publicKeyReference = NULL;
    }


    //        [queryPublicKey release];

} else { publicKeyReference = publicKey; }

return publicKeyReference;
}

- (void)generateKeyPair:(NSUInteger)keySize {
OSStatus sanityCheck = noErr;
publicKey = NULL;
privateKey = NULL;

//  LOGGING_FACILITY1( keySize == 512 || keySize == 1024 || keySize == 2048, @"%d is an invalid and unsupported key size.", keySize );

// First delete current keys.
//  [self deleteAsymmetricKeys];

// Container dictionaries.
NSMutableDictionary * privateKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary * publicKeyAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary * keyPairAttr = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

// Set top level dictionary for the keypair.
[keyPairAttr setObject:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeyType];
[keyPairAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInteger:keySize] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrKeySizeInBits];


// Set the public key dictionary.
[publicKeyAttr setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrIsPermanent];
[publicKeyAttr setObject:publicTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
// See SecKey.h to set other flag values.

// Set attributes to top level dictionary.
[keyPairAttr setObject:publicKeyAttr forKey:(__bridge id)kSecPublicKeyAttrs];

// SecKeyGeneratePair returns the SecKeyRefs just for educational purposes.
sanityCheck = SecKeyGeneratePair((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)keyPairAttr, &publicKey, &privateKey);
//  LOGGING_FACILITY( sanityCheck == noErr && publicKey != NULL && privateKey != NULL, @"Something really bad went wrong with generating the key pair." );
if(sanityCheck == noErr  && publicKey != NULL && privateKey != NULL)
{
    NSLog(@"Successful");
}
//  [privateKeyAttr release];
//  [publicKeyAttr release];
//  [keyPairAttr release];
}

-(NSString *)encryptRSA:(NSString *)plainTextString key:(SecKeyRef)publicKeyNext {
size_t cipherBufferSize = SecKeyGetBlockSize(publicKeyNext);
uint8_t *cipherBuffer = malloc(cipherBufferSize);
uint8_t *nonce = (uint8_t *)[plainTextString UTF8String];
SecKeyEncrypt(publicKeyNext,
              kSecPaddingOAEP,
              nonce,
              strlen( (char*)nonce ),
              &cipherBuffer[0],
              &cipherBufferSize);
NSData *encryptedData = [NSData dataWithBytes:cipherBuffer length:cipherBufferSize];
NSString* encryptedString       =   [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",encryptedData];
return encryptedString;
}
```

Comment: What if you use `[testPubKey bytes]` instead?

Comment: That really is just a stab in the dark, hence a comment.... You are providing the NSData object as a whole. I would definitely try providing the raw data it wraps instead (aka using `bytes`) when calling your `encryptRSA...` implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way

[Use Chilkat iOS RSA Library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/downloads_ios.asp). One major downside: cost $189! :O

The hard way

Parse the XML, use [SCZ-BasicEncodingRules-iOS](https://github.com/StCredZero/SCZ-BasicEncodingRules-iOS) to generate a public key data out of the modulus and exponent. If that works, create a dummy keychain using that public key ([follow sample code here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_SecKeyWrapper_m.html)), extract the public key now in SecKeyRef format and pass it to the encryptRSA method in the question. Finally, cleanup, remove the dummy keychain. Sounds good in theory, but I have never tested this thoroughly, if you do, let me know!

Comment: Why it doesn't work with a simple buffer like CCCrypt works with?